# Convert dbf file to csv

Tags: csv, dbf

Can someone help me to convert a small dbf file (113mb) to csv?
I have tried virtually all the online converter available, and it either fails or says that the file is too big.

Comment: What languages do you have available to work with. If you had Visual FoxPro, its a 2-liner.  Use theFile, copy to csv.    Is the .dbf file a free-table, or is it bound to a database container?  Is it a dBASE table or Visual FoxPro table, or other?  How do you access it now?  Please edit your existing post with the additional details vs adding a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using R, which is free and can be downloaded [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/)

The R script to read the dbf file and write a csv is:

```
install.packages("foreign")
library(foreign)
myFolder <- "C:\\Users\\yourFileLocation\\"
myFile <- "yourFile.dbf"
df <- read.dbf(paste(myFolder,myFile,sep=""))
myCsv <- "yourCsv.csv"
write.csv(df,paste(myFolder,myCsv))
```

There are no file size resrictions.